# tricky plsql procedure to delete data

Tags: oracle, plsql

Friends and pl/sql gurus...

I am trying to create procedure to delete data from audit table but don't know where to start with..

it will be great if somebody could provide some tips or pointer...

Requirements:

1. Procedure will run on first Saturday of the month (not sure is it possible via pl/sql or have to create separate job)
2. Delete data older than 2 months from Mon - Sat and date shouldn't be 1st of the month. (i.e. leave Sunday & 1st of the month data older than 2 months)

e.g.

```
*Procedure delete_log

IS

BEGIN


delete from audit_logs
where created >= trunc(sysdate - 60) and created < trunc(sysdate)
and created != (Sunday)
and created != (First of the month);

Commit;

End delete_log;*
```

I don't have much experience with pl/sql so all tips are appreciated..

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To schedule a job you can use a cron job at the server level or Oracle Scheduler to run tasks http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/scheduse002.htm#i1006395

Something like this would work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE delete_log
IS
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM audit_logs
         WHERE     TRUNC (created) < ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (SYSDATE), -2)
               AND TO_CHAR (TRUNC (created), 'DY') != 'SUN'
               AND TO_CHAR (TRUNC (created), 'DD') != '01';
END;
/
```

Comment: thank you... I will test this and let you know..just wondering can we user to_char and trunc in same syntax?

Comment: Yes, this is valid syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The DBMS_Scheduler calendaring syntax will support running a process on the first saturday of the month.

The syntax would be something like:

```
'FREQ=MONTHLY; BYDAY=SAT; BYSETPOS=1'
```

You'd add clauses for the exact time at which you want it to run.

```
'FREQ=MONTHLY; BYDAY=SAT; BYHOUR=3; BYMINUTE=30; BYSECOND = 0; BYSETPOS=1'
```

As far as the delete is concerned:

```
delete from audit_logs
where created                   <  add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),-2)   and
      to_char(created,'DY')     != 'SUN'                                and
      extract(DAY from created) != 1;
```

Comment: Ah, because the first day of the month is to be excluded anyway ;)

Comment: so answer provided by @verbanicm will do? or still +1 needed?

Comment: verbanicim's code deletes records older than two months ago, which does not seem to be what you are asking for according to your pseudo code. The TRUNC() on created is also redundant.

Comment: Thanks David.. my code syntax is not accurate but requirement stated was correct... needed to delete all records older than 2 months (leaving Sun and 01 data)